# How to get a control's handle in WinUI3 in C++?

Tags: c++, winrt-xaml, winui-3

I am working on a C++ WinUI3 project and got this problem. How do I obtain the handle of a XAML grid?

Something like this in QT can achieve it:

HWND m_hWnd;

m_hWnd = (HWND)(ui.label->winId());

But I couldn't find the similar thing in WinUI3.
I look up on the Internet, but only find this solution which is in C#:

[Get-a-controls-handle-in-XAML](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5280782/Get-a-controls-handle-in-XAML)

And the Microsoft provide this, but it is only working for window handle, not XAML controls.

[Retrieve a window handle (HWND)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/ui-input/retrieve-hwnd#winui-3-with-c-1)

Could anyone help me with it? Any suggestions will be great!

Comment: XAML is a windowless framework. Controls don't have windows.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how to get controls / elements handle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I obtain the handle of a XAML grid?

You can't because there is none.

All XAML controls on the screen are ultimately backed by a single HWND that belongs to the parent window, i.e. an individual control doesn't have its own handle in Win UI.

There is only a single top-level handle and the controls are rendered as content inside this HWND.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me. I now am trying to use webview2 to display videos on the page.